# Custom module multiple tabs and form in backend just like Customer backend

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, forms, backend, tabs

I have create a custom extension just like customer module and want backend just like customer .My extension have two tables and two table. My module are

```
Mage::getModel('custommod/reg').(just like Mage::getModel('customer/customer'));
 //reg save data of regsitration

 Mage::getModel('custommod/personal').(just like Mage::getModel('customer/address')); //personal data of a reg reords.
```

Please check the image [image]

Now I have to show the data and edit . In magento customer admin section, the customer edit position has multiple tabs: Account inforamtion, Address etc. Here,Account inforamton tab saves data in customer/customer and Address information tab saves data in customer/address

I like this type of section. I would like to  edit the contents of all tabs of my modules.

Comment: Follow the below link, It will be help you.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682911/how-to-add-grid-under-a-tab-in-magento-custom-admin-module][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682911/how-to-add-grid-under-a-tab-in-magento-custom-admin-module

Comment: Supravat ,i want to editing the content of second tabs also.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is kind of big.
If you expect a fully functional module I doubt you are going to get one.
But you can build your own.
Try to replicate the blocks and models in the customer admin section and add you logic.

I can recommend you [this module creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/moduleCreator). It doesn't do exactly what you need but it can kick start your project.

Now some pointers on what you need to do.
After setting up a simple form that manages your main entity (`custommod/reg`), you can add a second tab on the main add/edit form using

```
$this->addTab('personal', array(
    'label'     => $this->__('Personal data'),
    'content'   => 'content'     => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('{{module}}/adminhtml_{{entity}}_edit_tab_personal')->setTemplate('path/to/some/template.phtml')->toHtml(),
));
```

and in the template `path/to/some/template.phtml` add your logic for adding/editing the secondary entity (`custommod/personal`).

Then in the `saveAction` method of your controller handle the values submitted from the main form and from this secondary tab.